# How to recreate office group site url as same as deleted office group site url

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups

I have created a office 365 group and for some reason I have deleted it.

After 10 days when I tried to create new office group with same name, I am not able to create new office group with the same url as previously deleted group. However group alias are available but unfortunately site url is not so good.

For example:

If I try to create a office group with HR then site url is coming as `https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/HR20` or `https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/HR2` or `https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/HR48`, etc.

Is there any possibility to create HR office group by having url as `https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/HR`?

Comment: did you check using Powershell whether https://.sharepoint.com/HR still exists in the list of sites available in tenant

Comment: can you try `Clear-PnPTenantRecycleBinItem -Url https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/HR` and then try creating your site collection again ? Will require SP Admin privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that deleted site is still available in the recycle bin by using below powershell command

```
Connect-SPOService -URL https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com
Get-SPODeletedSites
```

if the deleted sites listed there ,then Remove-SPODeltedSite -Identity https://

once it successfully deleted from there then create your Site with old URL